# How do I convert a date string to my datetime format?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to convert a variable named `$releasedate` which contains the string `'May 31, 2011'` to the string `'2011-05-31 00:00:00'` to insert into the database.

I have tried...

```
$pubdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$releasedate);
```

...but it didn't work.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()`.

```
$pubdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($releasedate)); // 2011-05-31 00:00:00
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/YZFv1aK7).

Answer (score 2):

strtotime is the quick/easy version, and for a proper "english" date like this, it'd work fine. But it can quite easily choke on something like "01/02/03" (March 2, 2001? Feb 1st, 2003?). As well, there is a fair amount of parseing overhead to try and figure out what the string really is. If you know in advance what the date's format is, you'd be better off using `[date_create_from_format()][1]`:

```
$time = date_create_from_format('M j, Y', $release_date);
$formatted = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```